# testdisk live with btrfs support

Tags: btrfs, testdisk

I have a Fedora Silverblue 36 on btrfs

I accidentally erased some files and I'd like to use testdisk to try to recuperate them, at least partially

if I create a container with toolbox, it won't get access to the disk

I tried Ubuntu live and the testdisk available there had no btrfs support (a compilation flag)

The same goes with a Fedora live and a Kali Linux live

What can I do ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 1. Have you performed btrfs-rescue, https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-btrfs-rescue/ or  btrfs-restore, https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-btrfs-restore?

Comment: [SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/) has `testdisk` and many other tools.  I don't know if they will help you, but I've found `SystemRescue` very helpful for other tasks.